# access postgres into docker container when postgres locally is also running

Tags: postgresql, docker, psycopg2

I have postgres on docker container that I run using the following command:

```
docker run -d --name timescaledb -p 127.0.0.1:5433:5433 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=somepass timescale/timescaledb:latest-pg12
```

Meanwhile I also have postgres installed locally in my machine and port `5432` is listening:

```
    COMMAND    PID     USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
    postgres   124 postgres    7u  IPv6 0x38eef62419af50a3      0t0  TCP *:5432 (LISTEN)
    postgres   124 postgres    8u  IPv4 0x38eef624199e6d5b      0t0  TCP *:5432 (LISTEN)
    com.docke 3520     alex   39u  IPv4 0x38eef62428c6b7fb      0t0  TCP localhost:5433 (LISTEN)
    com.docke 3520     alex   42u  IPv4 0x38eef62428c3581b      0t0  TCP *:49816 (LISTEN)
```

I'm trying to set up a connection with `psycopg2` using this command:

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(host=config.DB_HOST,database=config.DB_NAME,user=config.DB_USER,password=config.DB_PASS,port=config.DB_PORT)
```

of which `config.xxx` is :

```
DB_HOST = 'localhost'
DB_USER = 'postgres'
DB_PASS = 'somepass'
DB_NAME = 'etfdb'
DB_PORT = '5433'
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
   conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5433 failed: Connection refused
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5433 failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
```

It's worth noting that the command `docker ps` shows me port `5432` for some reason I don't know:

```
❯ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                               COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS          PORTS                                NAMES
5d2623bd4055   timescale/timescaledb:latest-pg12   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 days ago   Up 17 minutes   5432/tcp, 127.0.0.1:5433->5433/tcp   timescaledb
```

Comment: You’re redirecting port 5433 to port 5433 in the container. You probably want to redirect 5433->5432 instead. The database in the container listens on 5432, not 5433, like `docker ps` shows

Comment: ok thanks will try, if I redirect 5432:5432 will create problems right ? because postgresql locally is also listening on this port

Comment: Yes, that’s why 5433->5432, not 5433->5433 or 5432->5432

Comment: ok thanks and what the `127.0.0.1:` does before `5433:5432` it assures only myself `localhost` can bind to this port ? is that correct to say ?

Comment: It defines where the port will be bound. IP:port for the bind, followed by container port. Currently it only allows local connections to port 5433, not from other machines. So you are correct